# Scalling out sklearn models / xgboost

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, sklearn-pandas

I wonder how / if it is possible to run sklearn models / xgboost training for a large dataset.
If I use a dataframe that contains several giga-bytes, the machine crashes during the training.

Can you assist me please?

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn documentation has an [in-depth discussion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/scaling_strategies.html) about different strategies  to scale models to bigger data.
Strategies include:

- Streaming instances
- Extracting features
- Incremental learning (see also the [`partial_fit` entry](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-partial_fit) in the [glossary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html))

Comment: [xgboost.train](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.train) accepts a parameter `xgb_model` to perform incremental learning.